# Error import web3

Tags: web3js, dapps

I can't import the web3 file there is an error ,SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I used npm, to install the web3 library

this error is in the phaser

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
const web3 = require("web3.js");
```

If you want to use the import statement you need to add a line in your package.json called "type": "module", learn more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-an-es6-import-in-node-js/#:%7E:text=The%20import%20statement%20is%20used,it%20is%20declared%20or%20not.&text=Node%20js%20doesn%27t%20support%20ES6%20import%20directly.).

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a JS error in general. You can use `const Web3 = require('web3');` to import.

```
//INDEX.JS file
const Web3 = require("web3"); //The keyword web3 is case sensative
const web3 = new Web3("RPC LINK"); //Connect to an RPC and start using web3

   ... //more code
```

Or you can edit package.json. You will need put `"type": "module",` at the root of your JSON file.

```
//PACKAGE.JSON file
{
  "name": "index",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",

   ... //more
   
}
```